# The degree of a circle function

Tags: general-topology

Does the degree of a circle function $f:S^1 \to S^1$ simply mean how many times the mapping of $f$ wraps around the $S^1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the degree of a continuous map $S^1 \to S^1$ counts how many times a loop wraps around the circle. Up to homotopy, loops in $S^1$ are classified by their degree: a loop wraps counterclockwise around the circle $n$ times iff it represents $n \in \mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(S^1)$ iff it is homotopic to the map $z \mapsto z^n$ (complex multiplication).